# SpaceVim: Error when installing [[custom_plugins]]: vimL function must not be called in a lua loop callback

Tags: vim, lua, neovim, spacevim

I'm giving SpaceVim a try.

I want to install the following [plugin (lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim)](https://github.com/lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim)

I get the following error:

```
Error executing luv callback:
.../lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim/lua/gitsigns/async.lua:67: The coroutine failed with this message: [string ":lua"]:4: E5560: vimL function must not be called in a lua loop callback
```

I tried the following [configurations (spacevim documentation)](https://spacevim.org/documentation/)

**Method 1**

```
# ~/.SpaceVim.d/init.toml

[options]
  ...
  bootstrap_after = 'myspacevim#after'

[[custom_plugins]]
  name = 'lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim'
  merged = false


# ~/.SpaceVim.d/autoload/myspacevim.vim

function! myspacevim#after() abort
lua << EOF
  require('gitsigns').setup({})
EOF
endfunction
```

**Method 2**

```
# ~/.SpaceVim.d/init.toml

[[custom_plugins]]
  name = 'lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim'
  merged = false
  hook_add = '''
  lua << EOF
  require('gitsigns').setup({})
EOF
'''
```

Without SpaceVim it's working perfectly with:

```
# ~/.config/nvim/init.vim

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim'
call plug#end()

lua << EOF
  require('gitsigns').setup({})
EOF
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to add post-initialization actions. Here is how I have configured [gp.nvim](https://github.com/Robitx/gp.nvim) plugin:

- In `init.toml` configuration file, in section `[options]` I've added a setting `bootstrap_after = 'myspacevim#after'`
- I've added the init section to file *~/.SpaceVim.d/autoload/myspacevim.vim*:

  ```
  function! myspacevim#after() abort
    lua << EOF
    require("gp").setup()
  EOF
  endfunction
  ```